# Save image on external Storage

Tags: android, save, android-external-storage

Hey I want to save an image in the external storage. I got two versions out of here but both aren't working. Goal is that the user clicks a button and the image is saved and then the user can also see it in the gallery. So here is Version one:

```
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            File outputDir= new File(path);
            outputDir.mkdirs();
            File newFile = new File(path+"/"+"test.png");
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                mutableBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And this is Version 2:

```
            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + "MyApplication";
            File outputDir= new File(path);
            outputDir.mkdirs();
            File newFile = new File(path+"/"+"test.png");
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                mutableBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` already is a folder, there's no need to remake it (or rather it's more like you can't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 AsyncTask fileTask = new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyApplication");
if (!directory.exists()) {
                    directory.mkdirs();
                }
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String name = " "+n+".jpg";
File pictureFile = new File(directory, name);
pictureFile.createNewFile();
try {
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
        }
    };
    fileTask.execute();
```

This should work fine provided all the file handling permissions are available for your app.

Also please note that you should never do file operations in the main thread thus always use AsyncTask if you haven't already done so.

Comment: also get a FileNotFindException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/saved_images/Image-7061.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Have you taken all the file handling  permissions? And explicit permission from the user if you're testing device is marshmallow and above?

Comment: Only got the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Device is Android Marshmallow 6.0.1 Need another permission?

Comment: Did you obtain the permission at the runtime from the user? Or did you just mention the permission in the manifest?

Comment: I thought if you start the app directly from android studio on your device you don't have to avail the permission?

Comment: @Luca486, the permission style has completely changed since Android Marshmallow. You have to ask the user at run time for the first time to avail the permission.

Please read through this - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Now, to do this, you have to options at hand :-
1) Open the build.gradle of your app and set the targetSDK to 22 (Not recommended)

2) Use this library https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher as it solves the problem of attaining the permission at runtime with 2-3 lines of code while keeping the targetSDK at 23 or above. :)

Comment: @Luca486 you have to avail the permission at runtime in any case for the first time or when the user has disabled the permission, on all marshmallow or post marshmallow devices. In lollipop or pre-lollipop devices, it would run just fine without any runtime permission.

Do mark this answer as correct if it solves your problem. :)

Comment: No problem bro.

Answer (score -1):

Late but might be helpful

```
private void saveimage(Bitmap img) {


                try {
                    String imageName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                    boolean imageSaved = false;
                    if (!(img == null || img.isRecycled())) {
                        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                        File file = new File(getStoragePath() + "img path/");
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            file.mkdirs();
                        }
                        File imageFile = new File(file, String.format("%s.png", new Object[]{imageName}));
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                            imageSaved = img.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                            if (out != null) {
                                out.flush();
                                out.close();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to write the image to gallery", e);
                        }
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(8);
                        values.put(SettingsJsonConstants.PROMPT_TITLE_KEY, imageName);
                        values.put("_display_name", camera.name);
                        String location = "";
                        if (camera.country != null && camera.country.length() > 0) {
                            location = camera.country;
                        }
                        if (camera.city != null && camera.city.length() > 0) {
                            location = location + ", " + camera.city;
                        }
                        values.put("description", location);
                        values.put("mime_type", "image/png");
                        values.put("description", "");
                        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        values.put("date_added", Long.valueOf(millis / 1000));
                        values.put("datetaken", Long.valueOf(millis));
                        values.put("_data", imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        contentResolver.insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]{imageFile.getPath()}, new String[]{"image/png"}, new OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if (imageSaved) {

                    }
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "saveSnapshot", e2);
                }




    }
```

Comment: I was going to edit the indentation/formatting but this code should be cleaned up and commented, downvote until improved