# Image is not being written in external Storage properly and NullPointerException

Tags: android, file, sockets

I am building an app using Android Studio where a client receives an image from the server, creates a new directory in the Gallery and saves the image in it.

Now, the new folder in gallery gets created, as well as the *`.jpg`* file, but that file cannot be opened. It just shows an ***"!"*** mark on the file. below is the code for my server and client:
After editing, I am getting a NullPointerException while executing mBitmap.compress on the byte array, even though I printed it and it is not null

```
//Server
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
try {
    InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(uri);
    System.out.println("cAME here");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)uri.getPath().length()];
    is.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    oos.writeObject(bytes);
    oos.flush();

    socket.close();

    final String sentMsg = "File sent to: " + socket.getInetAddress();
    ServerSocketThread.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(ServerSocketThread.this,
                sentMsg,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And now the client:

```
//Client
Socket socket = null;
Client.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(Client.this,
            "connected",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
try {
    socket = new Socket(address, portNumber);
    File fileDir = new File(Environment
        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "LetsShare");
    if(fileDir.exists() == false){
        fileDir.mkdirs();}
        File file = new File(fileDir,"test.jpg");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        byte[] bytes;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            bytes = (byte[])ois.readObject();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(bytes);

            Client.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Client.this,
                        "Finished",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            scanMedia(file.toString());
            //File toSet = new File(file.toString()); 
//imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(toSet.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why the image is not being saved properly and is unable to be opened?

edited client side:

```
  socket = new Socket(address, portNumber);
            File fileDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "LetsShare");
            if(fileDir.exists() == false){
            fileDir.mkdirs();}
            File file = new File(fileDir,"test.jpg");
            file.createNewFile();
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
           // int length = ois.readInt();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            try{
           bytes = (byte[])ois.readObject();}catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {

            }
            for (int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(bytes[i]);
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
            try {

                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                Client.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Client.this,
                                "Finished",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                scanMedia(file.toString());
                //File toSet = new File(file.toString());
                //imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(toSet.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
```

Comment: you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648947/save-image-on-external-storage

Comment: @mdb I saw that thread and after modifying my code, I got the following exception while running it on an android device: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib]]       Any idea why?

Comment: I guess this has something to do with Instant Run. Can you disable Instant run on your studio if its enabled and clean project and check?

Comment: @mdb yes after doing what you said, I am not getting that error. However, now I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.hp.letsshare.Client$ClientThread.run(Client.java:149)  exception, allthough I have printed the byte array and it is not null. I have edited the question for better understanding